# Use copies of a variable rather than reference

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access a copy of a variable, rather than the variable itself. 
For example, I want an enemy to drop a certain quantity of Bones when killed.

Enemy1: Drop 1 of Bones

Enemy2: Drop 2 of Bones

Rather than recreate this Item 'Bones' for every kind of enemy, I want to have one class that contains all Items, and enemies such as Enemy1 and Enemy2 can use AllItems.Bones to get the Bones drop. The problem occurs when I want to change the quantity variable of the drop object in Enemy2.cs. When I do 'drop.quantity = 2', the quantity of Enemy1's drop becomes 2 as well. Here's about the code I'm using:

```
//AllItems.cs
public class AllItems{
    public static Item Bones = new Item();
}

//Item.cs
public class Item{
    public int quantity = 1;
}

//Enemy1.cs
public class Enemy1{
    Item drop;
    public Enemy1(){
        drop = AllItems.bones;
    }
}

//Enemy2.cs
public class Enemy2{
    Item drop;
    public Enemy2(){
        drop = AllItems.bones;
        drop.quantity = 2;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set Enemy1's and Enemy2's Drop to AllItems.Bones and modify their drop without affecting the other's?

If there's a simple solution, my apologies. I've been looking for a long while now without success. I can give any additional info about why I'm doing something a certain way or how something is set up upon request.

Thank you.

Comment: why `Bones` in all items is `static` ?? change this and see what happens, when you use `static` it shares only one instance of that item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can simply change the `=` to `=>` in the property:

```
public static Item Bones => new Item();
```

This will create new `Item` each time it's accessed.

But i would rather create a function for creating a new set of bones - IMO it would be more intuitive and clear:

```
public class AllItems{
    public static Item CreateNewSetOfBones()
    { 
        return new Item();
    }
}
```

Or the short syntax:

```
public class AllItems{
    public static Item CreateNewSetOfBones() => new Item();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you use a `static` field or property, it shares only one instance everywhere.
Instead, I would suggest you to make it non-static. Following should do the trick.

```
//AllItems.cs
public class AllItems
{
    public static Item GetBones()
    {
        return new Item();
    }
}
```

Please let me know in case of any confusion.